# Why react default form feature is not executing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";

export default class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            value:""
        }
    }

    // handleClick
    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        return <>
            <h2>Typig ... {this.state.value}  </h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} onChange={this.handleClick}  />
            </form>
        </>
    }
}
```

I learnt that we can't change the value of any input tag in react, we have to do it manually by writing handler function but in the above code snippet i haven't change value explicitly then why here the default behaviour is not applied
In the above code snippet i have not change the value of the input tag explicitely then why react default feature is not applied here

Answer (score 1):

Transform your Input like this:

```
 <input type="text" value={this.state.value} ref={this.inputRef} onChange={e => this.handleClick}  />
```

Comment: @ahmedrazafarooqui then you cant use the state with that value